# How to use Multi NavigationLink in One Cell of List?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

NavigationLink in List is automatically designed.

How to set appropriate multi `NavigationLink` in Cell?

I don't want use `ForEach` in `ScrollView`. Because I want to use `swipeActions`.

I don't want user NavigationLink(isActive). Because It is deprecated in iOS 16

[image]

```swift
struct TimelineView: View {
  let tweets: [Tweet] = tweets
  let users: [User] = users

  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      List(tweets) { tweet in
        let user = users.first { $0.id == tweet.userID }!

        NavigationLink(value: tweet) {
          HStack {
            NavigationLink(value: user) {
              Image(systemName: "person")
                .foregroundStyle(user.color)
            }

            VStack {
              Text("@\(user.name)")
              Text(tweet.text)
            }
          }
        }
        .swipeActions(edge: .leading) {
          Button("Like") { }
        }
      }
      .navigationDestination(for: Tweet.self) { tweet in
        TweetDetailView(tweet: tweet)
      }
      .navigationDestination(for: User.self) { user in
        UserDetailView(user: user)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach is the same as before, ok, activation is now different, but simpler, just put value into `NavigationStack` path:

Here is a possible approach (based on tap gesture as we mentioned before) - Xcode 14b3 / iOS 16

[image]

```
@State var path = NavigationPath() // stack path

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack(path: $path) {
        List(tweets) { tweet in
            let user = users.first { $0.id == tweet.userID }!
            
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "person")
                    .foregroundStyle(user.color)
                    .padding(4)
                    .highPriorityGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                        path.append(user)      // << here !!
                    })
                Spacer()
                VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                    Text("@\(user.name)")
                    Text(tweet.text)
                }
            }
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture {
                path.append(tweet)        // << here !!
            }
```

[Test module on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/iOS16/TestTwoLinksInRowNavigationStack.swift)

Comment: Sorry. I forgot say target os is iOS 16.
NavigationLink(isActive) is deprecated in iOS 16.

Comment: I knew that it is for iOS 16, because NavigationStack mentioned, which is a new with SwiftUI 4, anyway the concept is the same. See updated with exact demo.