# NavigationLink isActive deprecated

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

In the new version of iOS and Xcode

```
NavigationLink(isActive: , destination: , label: )
```

is deprecated.

How do we control the status of NavigationLink then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use new `NavigationLink(value:label:)` as specified. By putting corresponding value into `NavigationPath` you activate a link.

See more for example in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72922096/12299030)

[image: demo]

Comment: I tried the example github code. it worked, but i still don't know how this new stack work. i will look into more information in documentation.

Answer (score 49):

Old/Deprecated way to navigate:

```
    @State private var readyToNavigate : Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: MyTargetView(), isActive: $readyToNavigate, label: {Text("Navigate Link")})
                
                Button {
                    //Code here before changing the bool value
                    readyToNavigate = true
                } label: {
                    Text("Navigate Button")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Navigation")
        }
    }
```

New way to navigate - note that this is using `NavigationStack` instead of `NavigationView`:

```
    @State private var readyToNavigate : Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
           VStack {
              Button {
                  //Code here before changing the bool value
                  readyToNavigate = true
              } label: {
                  Text("Navigate Button")
              }
          }
           .navigationTitle("Navigation")
           .navigationDestination(isPresented: $readyToNavigate) {
              MyTargetView()
          }
       }
   }
```

Comment: `isPresented: readyToNavigate` should be `isPresented: $readyToNavigate`

Comment: **Note that it's using a `NavigationStack` now, not a `NavigationView`. The answer here is perfect, I'm just adding this note for anybody (like me) who overlooked that new piece. It compiled fine with `NavigationView` and `.navigationDestination`, but just didn't go anywhere, and I went bonkers trying to figure out why, not realizing my eyes had fixated on the new `.navigationDestination` and overlooked the also-new `NavigationStack`.

Comment: It is only for IOS 16. For IOS 15 we can not use NavigationStack, but NavigationLink(isActive: , destination: , label: )  already marked like depricated.

Answer (score 3):

Check out Apple's migration docs:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types

Comment: I remember the days when it took more than two years to deprecate code. SwiftUI is doing it at a much faster rate. I feel like the current SwiftUI declarative method of building user interfaces is where the old UIKit was back in 2013...

Answer (score 0):

The `isActive` implementation of `NavigationLink` is deprecated in **iOS 16**. Instead, you should use the new `NavigationLink(value:)` along with `.navigationDestination` with `NavigationStack`.

Answer (score 0):

## in iOS16 and above

The new programmatic way to do navigation is extremely powerful! Much better than the old one.
The new way is using the `NavigationStack(path:root)`.
The path parameter is a Binding to a `NavigationPath`. ex.

```swift
@State private var path = NavigationPath()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
           ...
    }
```

Lets create two structs to illustrate how this works.

```swift
struct Fruit: Hashable,Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var number: Int
    static var sample = [Fruit(name: "Apple", number: 2), Fruit(name: "Cherry", number: 3)]
}

struct Vegetable: Hashable,Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var number: Int
    static var sample = [Vegetable(name: "Carrot", number: 2), Vegetable(name: "Zucchini", number: 3)]
}
```

The new navigation style is data driven.
Here I create the label and link...
`NavigationLink(value:label:)`
But the destination will be different if I have a fruit or a veg.

```swift
 .navigationDestination(for: Fruit.self) { fruit in
     VStack {
     ...
     }
```

So if I have a Vegetable or a Fruit model, depending of the data type selected in the link, the navigation destination will be different and it will present different views.

So let's put this in the NavigationStack. Lets start with the NavigationLink:

```swift
Form {
    Section("Fruits") {
       ForEach(Fruit.sample) { fruit in
          NavigationLink(value: fruit) {
               HStack {
                 Text("\(fruit.number)")
                 Text(fruit.name)
               }
           }
       }
    }
    Section("Veggies") {
        ForEach(Vegetable.sample) { fruit in
           NavigationLink(value: fruit) {
                 HStack {
                   Text("\(fruit.number)")
                   Text(fruit.name)
                 }
             }
           }
         }
     }
```

Now the `NavigationDestination` gonna look like this:

```swift
 .navigationDestination(for: Fruit.self) { fruit in
     VStack {
         Text(fruit.name)
         HStack{
             let count = path.count
             Text("level: \(count)")
         }
         Form {
             Section("Veggies") {
                 ForEach(Vegetable.sample) { veg in
                     NavigationLink(value: veg) {
                         HStack {
                             Text("\(veg.number)")
                             Text(veg.name)
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         Button("Unwind") {
             path.removeLast(path.count)
         }
     }
```

and below add again the same but for veggies like:

```swift
.navigationDestination(for: Vegetable.self) { veg in
         VStack {
                   ...
}
```

Now you can navigate from list to list and the app will show you how many level deep you are depending of how many items are collected in the path. Then you can unwind. This will reset the path property to empty and the start page will be shown again!

The screen will look like this... and the unwind button

[image]

and navigating...

[image]

I hope this helps!