# SwiftUI's new NavigationStack API doesn't work well with UIHostingController's nav bar

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a UIKit app and I migrated some of my screens to SwiftUI using UIHostingController. I used to be able to re-use the same nav bar of UIKit. But after switching to NavigationStack API, I wasn't able to replicate the same behavior.

Here's a complete reproducible code.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

struct ListView: View {
  
  @State var selectedString: String? = nil
  
  var body: some View {
    let details = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

    // No need to wrap under NavigationView, otherwise will have double Nav Bar
    // This will use the UIKit's nav bar
    List {
      ForEach(details, id: \.self) { detail in
        let destination = Text("This is a detailed page for \(detail)")
          .navigationTitle("Detail page")
        
        NavigationLink(
          detail,
          destination: destination,
          tag: detail,
          selection: $selectedString)
      }
    }
    .navigationTitle("List page")
  }
}

struct ListViewWithNewAPI: View {
  @State var selectedString: String? = nil
  
  var body: some View {
    let details = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
    
    NavigationStack {
      List(details, id: \.self, selection: $selectedString) { detail in
        NavigationLink(detail, value: detail)
      }
      .navigationDestination(item: $selectedString) { detail in
        Text("This is a detailed page for \(detail)")
          .navigationTitle("Detail page")
      }
      .navigationTitle("List page")
      .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
  }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @objc
  private func tapButton1() {
    let listVC = UIHostingController(rootView: ListView())
    navigationController?.pushViewController(listVC, animated: true)
  }
  
  @objc
  private func tapButton2() {
    let listVC = UIHostingController(rootView: ListViewWithNewAPI())
    navigationController?.pushViewController(listVC, animated: true)
  }
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    let button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
    button1.backgroundColor = .green
    button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapButton1), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button1)
    
    let button2 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 300, width: 100, height: 100))
    button2.backgroundColor = .red
    button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapButton2), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button2)
   
    navigationItem.title = "UIKit title"
  }
}
```

The storyboard file is pretty much the initial project, except that I embedded the VC under a nav vc.

[image]

In the above code, `ListView` is implemented using the deprecated `NavigationView`, which works well with `UIHostingController`. `ListViewWithNewAPI` is the new implementation using the new `NavigationStack` API, and I wasn't able to replicate the original behavior.

Here's a video comparing the 2 behaviors. Please use the sample code and play around, and see if we can achieve the original behavior using the new API.

[image]

Comment: You have 2 UINavigationControllers, Pick one. the one based on SwiftUI or the UIKit one

Comment: @loremipsum Yes I know, but the question here is - how do i do that? I'd like to pick the UIKit one like my original implementation. Feel free to play around with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NavigationStack replaces NavigationView. In your code you push the UIHostingController on a navigationController. The view in ListViewWithNewAPI however contains a NavigationStack. This means you have now have two levels of 'navigation stacks', leading to undesirable behaviour.

Here are three different options to resolve the issue:

1. One option is to get rid of the Navigation Controller in your story board. You cannot directly use a UIHostingController in a story board because it uses generics, but you can wrap it in a (non-UINavigationController) UIViewController. Or you can get rid of storyboards altogether and adopt the SwiftUI app life cycle. You can then use the code in ListViewWithNewAPI as-is.
2. You can keep using the NavigationLink(destination: label:), which is not deprecated and continues to work in combination with a UINavigationController. Unfortunately this means no programmatic or value-based navigation.

```
struct ListViewWithNewAPI: View {
    @State var selectedString: String? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        let details = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
        
        List(details, id: \.self, selection: $selectedString) { detail in
            NavigationLink {
                Text("This is a detailed page for \(detail)")
                    .navigationTitle("Detail page")
            } label: {
                Text(detail)
            }
            
        }
            .navigationTitle("List page")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

3. If you need to keep the UINavigationController (because of other UIKit-based code) AND you want programmatic/value-based navigation, you could do the following:

A navigation model to use in SwiftUI

```
class NavigationModel {
    var navigationController: UINavigationController?
    
    func push<V: View>(@ViewBuilder _ view: () -> V) {
        let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: view())
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Add the navigationController to the model and feed the model to your view

```
// property of ViewController
private let navigationModel = NavigationModel()

@objc
private func tapButton2() {
    navigationModel.navigationController = navigationController
    let rootView = ListViewNavigation(navigationModel: navigationModel)
    let hc = UIHostingController(rootView: rootView)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(hc, animated: true)
}
```

This is how you use the navigation model

```
struct ListViewNavigation: View {
    let navigationModel: NavigationModel
    
    let details = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
    
    var body: some View {
        List(details, id: \.self) { detail in
            Button(action: { navigateTo(detail) }) {
                Text("Go to \(detail)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func navigateTo(_ detail: String) {
        navigationModel.push {
            Text("This is a detail page for \(detail)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm confused - why do we have 2 details page here? (one inside NavigationLink, and one inside navigationDestination?

Comment: Sorry, the navigationDestination is superfluous. I’ll remove it from the answer.

Comment: How do you migrate the case with an `isActive`? From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74523702/767653, it looks like `isActive` is translated to `isPresented` inside `navigationDestination`, but your approach removed the NavigationStack, so can't use `navigationDestination`.

Comment: Correct. Using NavigationStack/NavigationSplitView introduces a new level of navigation below the UIKit UINavigationController. This  causes the undesired behaviour. Since navigationDestination NEEDS to be in either NavigationStack/NavigationSplitView you cannot use that. That means there are three options left: 1) use NavigationLink(destination: label:), you lose programmatic/value based navigation, 2) get rid of the UINavigationController or 3) roll your own programmatic/value based navigation (based on UINavigationController)

Comment: Can you explain more about 2) and 3)? if i don't use UINavigationController in UIKit, how do i navigate to the SwiftUI pages?

Comment: 2) the ViewController in your code is contained in a UINavigationController, otherwise its navigationController property would be nil. You then push the UIHostingController on the stack of the navigationController. If the UIHostingController would not be a child of a UINavigationController, you could use your ListViewWithNewAPI as-is.

Comment: In other words, get rid of the Navigation Controller in your storyboard (maybe get rid of the storyboard altogether and use the SwiftUI app life cycle).

Comment: I have some buttons in UIKit's nav bar that I'd like to keep, so removing nav controller isn't an option for me. The eventual goal is to adopt SwiftUI, but as intermediate step, I have to keep using UIKit. It's not like I can migrate 30K lines of code to SwiftUI in one commit or something

Comment: the code i gave is just example code, I have lots of screens not powered by SwiftUI. So I need that nav controller to navigate into those UIKit screens.

Comment: In that case you could use something like the 3rd option. Or, of course, stick to the deprecated navigation link methods for the duration of the SwiftUI migration.

Comment: I think im gonna use legacy API for $isActive case, and new APIs for other cases. I also have screens that's not part of the UIKit nav bar. I will wait for a few more days and see if there's any better solution. If not, then I will accept yours.

Comment: for future readers - `isActive` can be migrated using the `selection` API (e.g. `@State var selectedFeature: MyFeature?` where `MyFeature` is an enum with a single case. This basically maps an optional selection field to `isActive` boolean

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this double navigation bar issue (UIKit UINavigationController pushing a UIHostingController whose rootView had an embedded `NavigationStack`). For my use case I **really** wanted to keep programmatic `.navigationDestination(<type>) {…}` `NavigationStack` navigation, primarily as I needed to keep the destination views "lazy" (so older `NavigationLink(<destination>, <label>)` methods wouldn't have been "lazy" unless I went for significant hackery).

I also needed to keep the UIKit navigationController for the other non-SwiftUI portions of the app. So my solution was to hide the UIKit navbar within the SwiftUI view and then emulate the back button within the NavigationStack. The animations etc. aren't seamless however it was fine for my needs.

```swift
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct MyView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Blah blah blah...")
            }
            // SwiftUI navigation bar properties
            .navigationTitle("My View")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                // Emulate a back button to take us back to the UIKit controller
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    Button {
                        dismiss()
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        .toolbar(.hidden, for: .navigationBar) // Hide UIKit navigation bar
    }
}
```

I also needed a custom UIHostingController to re-display the UIKit navigation bar when transitioning from the SwiftUI view back to the UIKit one.

```swift
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
class MyViewHostingController: UIHostingController<MyView> {
    private var wasNavigationBarHidden: Bool?
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override init(rootView: MyView) {
        super.init(rootView: rootView)
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        wasNavigationBarHidden = navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        // Re-display the navigation bar
        if let wasNavigationBarHidden,
            let navigationController,
           navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden != wasNavigationBarHidden
        {
            navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = wasNavigationBarHidden
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but this means you lose the push animation, right?